# How to sum a column filtered by a categorical column in the same table in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get a sum of my sales figures by the product category from the a column in the same table

The original data is on the attached image.

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srgqg.png)

And what I'm trying to get is attached also and I am having trouble getting the right numbers for the last three columns

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ZKD.png)

I have tried the following code:

```
Boots_Sales = CALCULATE( SUM(Sheet1[Sales]), FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Product_Type]="Boots"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the above by making a measure instead of a column with the below formula:

boot1 = CALCULATE(SUM(original[Sales]),FILTER(original,original[Product type ]="Boots"))

This will have to do, I was trying to make a column because I wanted to do further calculations on the column but will just have to convert the measure into a column

Thanks